# Loading JSON data to a list in a particular order using PyMongo

Tags: json, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

Let's say I have the following document in a MongoDB database:

```
{
    "assist_leaders" : {
        "Steve Nash" : {
            "team" : "Phoenix Suns",
            "position" : "PG",
            "draft_data" : {
                "class" : 1996,
                "pick" : 15,
                "selected_by" : "Phoenix Suns",
                "college" : "Santa Clara"
            }
        },
        "LeBron James" : {
            "team" : "Cleveland Cavaliers",
            "position" : "SF",
            "draft_data" : {
                "class" : 2003,
                "pick" : 1,
                "selected_by" : "Cleveland Cavaliers",
                "college" : "None"
            }
        },
    }
}
```

I'm trying to collect a few values under `"draft_data"` for each player in an ORDERED list. The list needs to look like the following for this particular document:

```
[ [1996, 15, "Phoenix Suns"], [2003, 1, "Cleveland Cavaliers"] ]
```

That is, each nested list must contain the values corresponding to the "pick", "selected_by", and "class" keys, in that order. I also need the "Steve Nash" data to come before the "LeBron James" data.

How can I achieve this using pymongo? Note that the structure of the data is not set in stone so I can change this if that makes the code simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List comprehension is the way to go here (Note: don't forget .iteritems() in Python2 or .items() in Python3 or you'll get a `ValueError: too many values to unpack`).

```
import pymongo
import numpy as np
client = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = client[database_name]

dataList = [v for i in ["Steve Nash", "LeBron James"]
            for key in ["class", "pick", "selected_by"]
            for document in db.collection_name.find({"assist_leaders": {"$exists": 1}})
            for k, v in document["assist_leaders"][i]["draft_data"].iteritems()
            if k == key]

print dataList
# [1996, 15, "Phoenix Suns", 2003, 1, "Cleveland Cavaliers"]

matrix = np.reshape(dataList, [2,3])

print matrix
# [ [1996, 15, "Phoenix Suns"],
#   [2003, 1, "Cleveland Cavaliers"] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd extract the data and turn it into a list in Python, once you've retrieved the document from MongoDB:

```
for doc in db.collection.find():
    for name, info in doc['assist_leaders'].items():
        draft_data = info['draft_data']
        lst = [draft_data['class'], draft_data['pick'], draft_data['selected_by']]
        print name, lst
```

Comment: I need the data stored in a single list